# Is it effective to control synchronization map using synchronized (map)?

Tags: java, java-8, synchronized

I create a map to store the value,but I find that sometimes the value is wrong with multi-thread concurrency problem.So I wonder if the GC is happen,do the `synchronized (map)` code can only allow one thread to run?I find the after gc,the map's hashcode may be changed.

```
private static Map<String, Map<String,String>> instanceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
//some thread to put key to instanceMap
//some thread to checkMapState
private void checkMapState(String key){
    Map localMap=instanceMap.get(key);
    synchronized (localMap) {
        if (localMap.containsKey(key)) {
            //code to clear map by key
            //log the same key not only one time
            log.info("key:{} have enter synchronized code",key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only get concurrency problems if a thread is modifying the map after it has been stored in the `ConcurrentHashMap`. In this case, it is not enough to put a `synchronized` around the reading side; *every access* must consistently use `synchronized`. When you go this road, you can use a [synchronized map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)) in the first place but it might be better to rethink the overall design as you’re not using the benefits of a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: @Holger,If I use `private static Map<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>> instanceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();`,do it also have  concurrency problems?

Comment: Most likely, you’ll still have problems. The `ConcurrentHashMap` guarantees that the internals of the map will always be in a consistent state, but it can’t prevent you from errors *in your program logic*. And processing a map while another thread changes it, implies a high probability that there are problems with your program logic. Further, calling `containsKey(key)` followed by some other actions, indicates a check-then-act pattern which can’t work with a `ConcurrentHashMap`. You’ll need `synchronized` or a lock for such code, but as said, all other accesses to the map will need it as well.